# Copying a c-string from 1 buffer to another in a child process using memcpy or strcpy does not seem to work

Tags: c

I am trying to write a mock shell that saves command line history and overrides the signal action for `SIGINT` to trigger printing the previous 10 commands entered by the user. As far as I am aware, everything from handling all of the signals to updating cursor and running commands using `execvp` works fine.

I however am running into 2 problems that I am having a hard time trying to wrap my head around.

1. Trouble trying to actually copy the contents of the input buffer to my own c-string vector, namely `histv`. After calling `read` and storing user input in `buf`, I try to copy the contents of `buf` to the location at `histv[cursor % MAX_HISTORY]` (the reason I am using modulus is because it seems easier to use a kind of circular array instead of handling the case that cursor rises to some number greater than `MAX_HISTORY`)
2. When I try running the process as a background process I always get an execvp error, even when the command is valid. I know it's happing after the parent process gets the `SIGUSR2` signal and creates a new child to run the commands. So I am assuming it has something to do with what happens to `argv` after the child process kills itself and raises `SIGUSR2`

Below is the code for the entire program. It is a bit messy in some spots, but overall it's rather simple. I have used all of `memcpy`, `strcpy`, and `strncpy` to no avail. They all compile and run without errors, but none of them seem to do anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// limits
#define MAX_LINE 80
#define MAX_HISTORY 10

// function headers
void print_history(unsigned int const, char**);
void handler_func(int);
void read_func(char*[], char[], char**, unsigned int const);
int parse_args(char*, char**, size_t);

// globals
volatile sig_atomic_t sig_caught = 0;

void print_history (const unsigned int cursor, char **histv) {
    int temp = (cursor > MAX_HISTORY) ? (cursor - MAX_HISTORY) : 0;

    puts("\n\nprinting the previous ten commands...");
    printf("cursor %d", cursor);

    for (int i = 1; temp < cursor; temp++) {
        printf("%d%s\n", i++, histv[temp % MAX_HISTORY]);
    }
}

void handler_func(int sig)
{   
    /* update loop control variable */
    sig_caught = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    // declare sigaction struct
    struct sigaction sigactor;

    // initialize sigaction struct
    sigactor.sa_handler = handler_func;
    sigemptyset(&sigactor.sa_mask);
    sigactor.sa_flags = 0;

    // set up sigaction for SIGINT
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sigactor, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("siagction() failed");
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    // set the buffer to no buffering
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    unsigned int cursor = 0;

    /* initlialize history vector */
    char **histv = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_HISTORY);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_HISTORY; i++) 
        histv[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LINE);

    // enter shell loop
    while (1) {

        /* fork process and get child pid */
        int cpid;

        char *argsv[MAX_LINE/2+1];
        char buf[MAX_LINE];


        while(!sig_caught) {

            cpid = fork();

            /* child */
            if (cpid == 0) {
                read_func(argsv, buf, histv, cursor);
            }

            /* fork error */
            else if (cpid < 0) {
                perror("Error forking process");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            /* parent process begins here */
            else {

                /* variable to store status returned from child*/
                int cstatus;

                /* suspend parent until child exits *
                 * store return status in cstatus   */
                waitpid(cpid, &cstatus, 0);

                /* get status from child process and check for SIGTERM *
                 * SIGTERM is raised by child when someone enters '!q' */
                switch(WTERMSIG(cstatus))
                {
                /* user wants to quit */
                case SIGTERM:
                    puts("User issued quit command");
                    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_HISTORY; i++) 
                        free((void *)histv[i]);
                    free((void *)histv);
                    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

                /* invalid string length */
                case SIGUSR1: 
                    puts("Please enter a valid string");
                    break;

                /* background process */
                case SIGUSR2:
                    cpid = fork();
                    if (cpid < 0) perror("Error forking process...");
                    else if (cpid == 0) {
                        if (execvp(argsv[0], argsv) < 0) {
                            --cursor;
                            perror("execvp");
                            kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!sig_caught) cursor++;
            }

        }// signal loop

        kill (cpid, SIGTERM);
        print_history(cursor, histv);
        fflush(stdout);
        sig_caught = 0;

    }
}

void read_func(char *argsv[], char buf[], char *histv[], unsigned int const cursor)
{
    printf("\nCMD > ");

    int background = 0;

    size_t length = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, MAX_LINE);

    if (length > 80 || length <= 0) kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);

    /* copy buffer into history and update cursor */
    memcpy(histv[cursor % MAX_HISTORY], buf, length);

    printf("cursor %d", cursor);
    /* parse arguments and return number of arguments */
    background = parse_args(buf, argsv, length);

    /* user entered quit command or string is invalid */
    if (background == -1) kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);

    /* signal parent to run process in the background */
    if (background == 1) kill(getpid(), SIGUSR2);

    /* run command */
    if (execvp(argsv[0], argsv) < 0) {
        perror("execvp");
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}

int parse_args(char buf[], char *argsv[], size_t length)
{

    int i,      /* loop index for accessing buf array */
        start,  /* index where beginning of next command parameter is */
        ct,     /* index of where to place the next parameter into args[] */
        bckg;   /* background flag */


    /* read what the user enters on the command line */
    ct = 0;
    start = -1;
    bckg = 0;

    if (buf[0] == '!' && buf[1] == 'q') return -1;

    /* examine every character in the buf */
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        switch (buf[i]){
            case ' ':
            case '\t':       /* argument separators */
                if(start != -1){
                    argsv[ct] = &buf[start];    /* set up pointer */
                    ct++;
                }
                buf[i] = '\0'; /* add a null char; make a C string */
                start = -1;
                break;

            case '\n':                 /* should be the final char examined */  
                if (start != -1){
                    argsv[ct] = &buf[start];
                    ct++;
                }
                buf[i] = '\0';
                argsv[ct] = NULL; /* no more arguments to this command */
                break;

            case '&':
                bckg = 1;
                buf[i] = '\0';
                break;

            default:             /* some other character */
                if (start == -1)
                    start = i;
        }
    }
    argsv[ct] = NULL; /* just in case the input line was > 80 */

    return bckg;
}
```

Side note, the `parse_args` function was initially given to us and I changed it a bit to work with the rest of program, but for the most part I did not write that function.

Please go easy on me, it's been a long time since I've used C for anything and a lot of what I am doing here took a lot of effort to begin understanding how this program behaves. (~:

Comment: forked process have a different memory space from their parent.

Comment: Uh ... remember that memory isn't shared between the parent and child. If you only write the data in the child, of course you'll never see it in the parent. While it's possible, that's not what you want here - instead, read the input and add it to history *before* `fork`ing and trying to execute it.

Comment: Also, `kill(getpid(), sig)` is just `raise(sig)`.

Comment: @o11c Yes, I know. But I am using kill because I want to be thorough for my own sake.

Comment: @o11c But considering that they don't share memory space, if I used thread local storage for the history vector would I see a difference? Or would that not change anything because I am forking processes and not creating threads? Are globals also copied over to a new memory space for the child?

Comment: @kohai All pages are copied (actually CoWed), unless they came from `mmap(..., flags=MAP_SHARED)` (or are accessing a device with a driver that forces sharing I guess). Other shared-memory APIs are implemented in terms of that, and that's what `strace` will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So both of the problems was with the fact that the memory wasn't being shared, as [o11c described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150085/copying-a-c-string-from-1-buffer-to-another-in-a-child-process-using-memcpy-or-s?noredirect=1#comment104525806_59150085). I fixed the issue by using `mmap` instead of `malloc` which in turn simplified my program as I no longer had to handle the memory management. Changes are described below.

```
char **histv = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_HISTORY);
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_HISTORY; i++) 
    histv[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LINE);
```

was changed to

```
char **histv = (char**)mmap(NULL, (sizeof(char*) * MAX_HISTORY), (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), (MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS), -1, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_HISTORY; i++) histv[i] = (char*)mmap(NULL,  (sizeof(char) * MAX_LINE), (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), (MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS), -1, 0);
```

While I do not know if this is the *best* way to do this, it solved my problem.

Also note that I did explicitly unmap the memory using `munmap` even though it technically should be handled automatically on exit.

Comment: It's always good practice to `free()` or `munmap()` before you exit even though it will happen on exit. It builds good habits for when you are writing functions and using allocations or maps that will not exit soon after then end of a function or spawned process.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica That is a really good point, thank you!